# Determining $A = \{n\in\Bbb N : n\ge2$ and there exists a branch of $\sqrt[n]{f}$ in $D \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

Consider $D = \Bbb C\setminus(\{e^{i\theta} : -\frac\pi2\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\}\cup(-\infty,0])$ and $f(z) = z(z^2+1)$. We know that $f$ can't be zero for any $z\in D$. If we consider now $A = \{n\in\Bbb N : n\ge2$ and there exists a branch of $\sqrt[n]{f}$ in $D \}$, what is $A$ exactly?

I tried the following: Take $\Gamma$ any closed curve (the only ones that interest us are the ones that go around $\{e^{i\theta} : -\frac\pi2\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\}$)
\begin{equation}
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\;dz = \frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\left(\frac1{z}+\frac1{z-i}+\frac1{z+i}\right)\;dz = n(\Gamma,0) + n(\Gamma,i) + n(\Gamma,-i) = 2n(\Gamma,i)
\end{equation}
With this, the only possibility is that $A\subset2\Bbb N$.

Rewrite $f(z) = \frac{z(z-i)}{(z+i)}(z+i)^2 = g(z)h(z)$, with $g(z) = \frac{z(z-i)}{(z+i)}$ and $h(z) = (z+i)^2$. By the same procedure as before, we know that $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}\;dz = 0$, so there exists a branch for $\log(g)$, which means that there exists a branch for $\sqrt[n]g$ for any $n\ge2$. The branch for $\sqrt h$ is just $z+i$, so we know that there exists at least a branch of $\sqrt f$, so $\{2\}\subset A \subset 2\Bbb N$.

Can we say that $A$ is either $\{2\}$ of $2\Bbb N$?

If we instead consider $D' = \Bbb C\setminus(\{e^{i\theta} : -\frac\pi2\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\}\cup[-1,2])$, for that same $f$ we would get $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\;dz = 3n(\Gamma,0)$, and by the same reasoning as before, $\{3\}\subset A'\subset3\Bbb N$. Could the same result for $A$ be said for $A'$ (but with $3$'s instead of $2$'s now)?

Comment: Does $X\setminus Y\cup Z$ mean $(X\setminus Y)\cup Z$ or $X\setminus (Y\cup Z)$? I tend to read it as the former, but that does not make sense here, so perhaps I am simply unaware of a commonly used precedence rule?

Comment: @MartinR I meant to say $\Bbb N$. And that's what I meant in the second comment. I just changed both things now, thanks for noticing! And sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I thought it would be clear, but I just changed it to show that I meant $X\setminus(Y\cup Z)$.

Comment: Very true. I'm so sorry for not double checking. Just edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll use a capital “N” for the winding number in order to avoid confusion with the exponent $n$).

You correctly derived that
$$
\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz = 2 N(\Gamma, i)
$$
is an even number for all closed curves $\Gamma$ in $D$, and concluded that $f$ has a holomorphic square root in $D$.

Now note that $\Gamma$ can be chosen such that $N(\Gamma, i) = 2$.
Then $f = g^n$ with a holomorphic function $g$ in $D$ implies
$$
\frac 2n  = \frac 1 n\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz = \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}\,dz =  N(g \circ \Gamma, 0)
$$
and since the right-hand side is an integer it follows that $n=1$ or $n=2$.

So the answer to your question is that $A = \{ 2 \}$.

Generally one can show that $f$ has a holomorphic $n$-th root in a domain $D$ if and only if $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\Gamma}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz$ is a multiple of $n$ for all closed curves $\Gamma$ in $D$.

Comment: Great! Likewise, with $D'$ we would get that $A'=\{3\}$, I'd imagine. Thank you so much for answering!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $\sqrt[nm] f$ exists, then so does $(\sqrt[nm] f)^m$.

Comment: In this case we would need the other implication. Is it true, though?

Comment: @GreekCorpse If you already now that $A\subseteq 2\Bbb N$, then certainly $42\notin A$ because that would require $7\in A$.

Comment: Oh I see it now! Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: One more thing, this only shows us that $\{2\}\subset A \subset \{2^n : n\in\Bbb N\}$, right? How can we say that $A$ is now either of those sets?